# how to bind search query variable to input field AND use it with computed function in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a very simple Vue js App that simply takes a query as input and print out the search results from a json file.

I want to bind my query variable to input field with id=search and call the computed function in search() to filter contacts by name, email phone...

My problem is that i dont really understand why `computed:` is not called when i type in my input field.

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Two way bind query to this input field -->
    <input id="search" v-model="query" type="text">
    <br>
    query input: <span>{{ query }}</span>

    <!--
      need to edit app-contacts component to receive
      contacts property through search results
    -->
    <app-contacts></app-contacts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Contacts from './components/Contacts'
import jsonContacts from './assets/contacts.json'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'app-contacts': Contacts
  },
  data () {
    return {
      contacts: jsonContacts,
      query: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    search: {
      get: function (query) {
        console.log('hello?')
        console.log(query)
        return ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Contacts.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-bind="contacts" v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id" class="con">
      <li>{{ contact.firstname }} {{ contact.lastname }} </li>
      <li v-for="email in contact.email" :key="email"  >{{ email }} </li>
      <li v-for="number in contact.phoneNumber" :key="number">{{ number }} </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- To continue -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  data () {
    return {
      query: ''
    }
  },
  props: {
    contacts: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

contacts.json

```json
[
  {
      "id": 1,
        "phoneNumber": [
            "3908902"
        ],
        "email": [
            "jamie@fox.com"
        ],
        "firstname": "Jamie",
        "lastname": "Fox"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
        "phoneNumber": [
            "123123333"
        ],
        "email": [
            "john@brown.com"
        ],
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Brown"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
        "phoneNumber": [
            "3131131"
        ],
        "email": [
            "John@jane.com"
        ],
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Jane"
  },
  {
      "id": 4,
        "phoneNumber": [
            "12122-043"
        ],
        "email": [
            "Kaien@Burrell.Com"
        ],
        "firstname": "Kaien",
        "lastname": "Burrell"
  },
  {
      "id": 5,
        "phoneNumber": [
            "3333333331",
            "3333333393",
            "333333333333"
        ],
        "email": [
            "randy@combs.com",
            "rb@randyburrell.info"
        ],
        "firstname": "Randy",
        "lastname": "combs"
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you miss to pass the `contacts` prop to `app-contacts` component... as you only render in that component, you need to pass the contacts to render, like `<app-contacts :contacts="filteredContacts" />` and have those `filteredContacts` as computed, plus, add `props: { contacts: Array }` to your contact component definition so it can accept the data via props...

Comment: @balexandre Thanks for your answer, im very new with Vue.. How and where do i return filteredContacts to be detected by <app-contacts :contacts="filteredContacts" />? I still dont understand why computed: is not called for search

Comment: @balexandre I think my function search  needs to return filteredContacts, but it's not even being called.. im not sure why?

Comment: I then will recommend some nice VueJs tutorial, like VueMastery or Vue school or even a full [VueJs course on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wy9q22isx3U) ... regarding my idea, something like this -> https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-shamir-c0clo?file=/src/App.vue - just realize that I' only filtering by `firstname` as you can see in code, and it's case sensitive, just so you get the idea

Comment: @balexandre Thank you! it worked, could you just explain the query you used, its pretty hard to read. You can write an answer ill accept it

Comment: what query?... the `.filter(function(x) { return x.firstname.includes(_.query) })` ? that's just a very basic use of [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @balexandre i did read it again and right, i understand it now. If you want to write an answer so i can give you ur reputation points go ahead :) Thanks